# Reverse proxy settings ignored

Tags: reverse-proxy, apache-2.4, mod-proxy, proxypass

After switching from Windows 8 Apache 2.2 or 2.4 (don't remember), 32bit to **Apache 2.4.9, 64 bit, Windows 8.1** my proxy settings are ignored.

All requests end up going to the default C:/wamp/www.

The hosts files has IP addresses for the second machine, to which I want to proxy the requests, just like before reinstalling.

hosts file:
`192.168.111.3       gitlab.kakao.ro`

httpd-vhosts.cong:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
    ServerName kakao.ro
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://gitlab.kakao.ro:60080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://gitlab.kakao.ro:60080/

    ServerName gitlab.kakao.ro
</VirtualHost>
```

Note: When making calls from the machine, the proxy is bypassed, because the hosts file directs the browser straight to the VM.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out.

The include was commented:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```